# tensorflow tf getting error cross entropy in built function

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have two functions as below, they come from Andrew Ng is deep learning course on coursera. The first function runs, but the second doesn't. logits and labels variables have the same shape as per the document [requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) I changed cost to `[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]`, but it didn't help :(

in case of the first function I am directly passing variables from the function call into the function

1)

```
def one_hot_matrix(labels, C):
    """
    Creates a matrix where the i-th row corresponds to the ith class number and the jth column
                     corresponds to the jth training example. So if example j had a label i. Then entry (i,j) 
                     will be 1. 

    Arguments:
    labels -- vector containing the labels 
    C -- number of classes, the depth of the one hot dimension

    Returns: 
    one_hot -- one hot matrix
    """

    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Create a tf.constant equal to C (depth), name it 'C'. (approx. 1 line)
    #C = tf.constant(C, name = 'C')
    #C = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name = 'C')
    #labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name = 'labels')

    # Use tf.one_hot, be careful with the axis (approx. 1 line)
    one_hot_matrix = tf.one_hot(labels, C, axis=0)

    # Create the session (approx. 1 line)
    sess = tf.Session()

    # Run the session (approx. 1 line)
    #one_hot = sess.run(one_hot_matrix)
    one_hot = sess.run(one_hot_matrix)

    # Close the session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.
    sess.close()

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return one_hot

labels = np.array([1,2,3,0,2,1])
one_hot = one_hot_matrix(labels, C = 4)
print ("one_hot = " + str(one_hot))
```

2)

```
    def cost(logits, labels):
    """
    Computes the cost using the sigmoid cross entropy
    
    Arguments:
    logits -- vector containing z, output of the last linear unit (before the final sigmoid activation)
    labels -- vector of labels y (1 or 0) 

    Note: What we've been calling "z" and "y" in this class are respectively called "logits" and "labels" 
    in the TensorFlow documentation. So logits will feed into z, and labels into y. 
    
    Returns:
    cost -- runs the session of the cost (formula (2))
    """

    ### START CODE HERE ### 

    # Create the placeholders for "logits" (z) and "labels" (y) (approx. 2 lines)
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'z')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'y')



    # Use the loss function (approx. 1 line)
    #cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = z,  labels = y)
    cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,  labels=labels)

    # Create a session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.
    sess = tf.Session()

    # Run the session (approx. 1 line).
    #cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {z: logits, y:labels})
    cost = sess.run(cost)

    # Close the session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.
    sess.close()

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return cost

logits = sigmoid(np.array([0.2,0.4,0.7,0.9]))
cost = cost(logits, np.array([0,0,1,1]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

The error is

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-51f13e22d2ec> in <module>()
      1 logits = sigmoid(np.array([0.2,0.4,0.7,0.9]))
----> 2 cost = cost(logits, np.array([0,0,1,1]))
      3 print ("cost = " + str(cost))

<ipython-input-60-3febf014323d> in cost(logits, labels)
     26     # Use the loss function (approx. 1 line)
     27     #cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = z,  labels = y)
---> 28     cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,  labels=labels)
     29 
     30     # Create a session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(_sentinel, labels, logits, name)
    169     relu_logits = array_ops.where(cond, logits, zeros)
    170     neg_abs_logits = array_ops.where(cond, -logits, logits)
--> 171     return math_ops.add(relu_logits - logits * labels,
    172                         math_ops.log1p(math_ops.exp(neg_abs_logits)),
    173                         name=name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    827       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    828         try:
--> 829           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    830         except TypeError:
    831           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    674       name=name,
    675       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 676       as_ref=False)
    677 
    678 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype)
    739 
    740         if ret is None:
--> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    742 
    743         if ret is NotImplemented:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    612     raise ValueError(
    613         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r"
--> 614         % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    615   return t
    616 

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("logistic_loss_4/labels:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int64)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not a problem that you've commented the lines were you create C as a tensorflow constant? Try to uncomment that line again and also add C as value. So it should look like this:

```
C = tf.constant(C,tf.int32, name = "C")
```

So you assign the value that you get as parameter to the Tensorflow constant C.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to map de feed_dict in  one_hot = sess.run(one_hot_matrix) something like:

```
one_hot = sess.run(one_hot_matrix, feed_dict={labels:labels, C:C})
```

Answer (score 0):

2) This is what you need to do. See below:

```
   ### START CODE HERE ### 

# Create the placeholders for "logits" (z) and "labels" (y) (approx. 2 lines)
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float64 , name='z')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64 , name='y')

# Use the loss function (approx. 1 line)
cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=z,  labels=y)

# Create a session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.
sess = tf.Session()

# Run the session (approx. 1 line).
cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={z:logits, y:labels})

# Close the session (approx. 1 line). See method 1 above.
sess.close()

### END CODE HERE ###

return cost
```